# MVVMで設計した際のModalを挟んだ画面遷移の実装について

Tags: swift, swiftui, mvvm, combine

SwiftUIのCombineを用いたMVVMで以下のような動作をどう組むか考えていました。
以下の実装方法についてお聞きしたいことがあります。

#### 【実装したい動作】

1. 人名のリストを表示
2. そのうち一つを選ぶと確認画面がmodalで表示される
3. modalで確認を押すと、その人物についてのページを表示する

#### 【実装結果】

- ContentView.swift

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct Person: Identifiable, Hashable {
  var id: UUID = UUID()
  var name: String
  var age: Int
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @ObservedObject var contentViewModel = ContentViewModel()
  var persons: [Person] = [Person(name: "taro", age: 10), Person(name: "hoge", age: 15)]
  
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      VStack {
        ForEach(self.persons) { person in
          NavigationLink(
            destination: NavView(person: person),
            tag: person,
            selection: self.$contentViewModel.selectedPerson
          ){
            Text(person.name)
              .onTapGesture(perform: {
                self.contentViewModel.apply(.signIn(person: person))
              })
              .sheet(isPresented: self.$contentViewModel.isShow, content: {
                ModalView(
                  modalViewModel: self.contentViewModel.modalViewModel,
                  person: self.contentViewModel.targetPerson!
                )
              })
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

struct ModalView: View {
  @ObservedObject var modalViewModel: ModalViewModel
  var person: Person
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("\(person.name)です")
      Button("Confirm") {
        self.modalViewModel.apply(.confirm)
      }
    }
  }
}

struct NavView: View {
  var person: Person
  
  var body: some View {
    Text("\(person.name)です!!!!")
  }
}
```

- ViewModel.swift

```swift
import Combine
import SwiftUI

class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
  // MARK: - Inputs
  enum Inputs {
    case signIn(person: Person)
  }
  var targetPerson: Person?
  
  // MARK: - Outputs
  @Published var isShow = false
  @Published var isConfirmed = false
  @Published var selectedPerson: Person?
  
  // MARK: - Privates
  private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
  
  @ObservedObject var modalViewModel = ModalViewModel()
  
  init(){
    self.bind()
  }
  
  func apply(_ action: Inputs) {
    switch action {
      case .signIn(let person):
        self.targetPerson = person
        self.isShow = true
    }
  }
  
  func bind() {
    self.modalViewModel
      .$isConfirmed
      .print("変更されました→\(isConfirmed)")
      .sink { (isConfirmed) in
        if isConfirmed {
          self.selectedPerson = self.targetPerson
          self.isShow = false
        }
      }
      .store(in: &cancellables)
  }
}

class ModalViewModel: ObservableObject {
  // MARK: - Inputs
  enum Inputs {
    case confirm
  }
  
  // MARK: - Outputs
  @Published var isConfirmed = false
  
  init(){}
  
  func apply(_ action: Inputs) {
    switch action {
      case .confirm:
        self.isConfirmed = true
    }
  }
}
```

これらの実装で望む動作は実現できました。

#### 【お聞きしたいこと】

1. ContentViewModelとModalViewModelどちらもにisConfirmedがあるのは仕方ないのでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: [コードレビュー的な質問はどこまでOKですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2939/)を参考にすると　２の質問は具体的でよいですが1や３は明確な答えが出せない可能性もあるのでオフトピック気味で回答が集まりにくいかもしれないです。絞るか論点を変えたほうがいいかもしれないですね。

Comment: ありがとうございます、少し考えますが質問内容を絞らせていただきたいと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ContentViewModelとModalViewModelどちらもにisConfirmedがあるのは仕方ないのでしょうか？

そもそも `ContentViewModel`の`isConfirmed`は `print` でしか使われていません。
（そして値も変わることがなさそうです。つまり使われていないと言えます）

よって、根本的にこの質問は成り立たないように感じます（`ContentViewModel`の`isConfirmed`は削除しまってよいと考えます）。

下記は`ContentViewModel`の`isConfirmed`に関する部分をコメントアウトして実際に試したコードです（全コードを1ファイルに載せるのは、お作法的にはよろしくないですが...）。意図通りの動きをすると思います。宣言とprintの2箇所コメントアウトしています。

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct Person: Identifiable, Hashable {
  var id: UUID = UUID()
  var name: String
  var age: Int
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @ObservedObject var contentViewModel = ContentViewModel()
  var persons: [Person] = [Person(name: "taro", age: 10), Person(name: "hoge", age: 15)]
  
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      VStack {
        ForEach(self.persons) { person in
          NavigationLink(
            destination: NavView(person: person),
            tag: person,
            selection: self.$contentViewModel.selectedPerson
          ){
            Text(person.name)
              .onTapGesture(perform: {
                self.contentViewModel.apply(.signIn(person: person))
              })
              .sheet(isPresented: self.$contentViewModel.isShow, content: {
                ModalView(
                  modalViewModel: self.contentViewModel.modalViewModel,
                  person: self.contentViewModel.targetPerson!
                )
              })
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

struct ModalView: View {
  @ObservedObject var modalViewModel: ModalViewModel
  var person: Person
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("\(person.name)です")
      Button("Confirm") {
        self.modalViewModel.apply(.confirm)
      }
    }
  }
}

struct NavView: View {
  var person: Person
  
  var body: some View {
    Text("\(person.name)です!!!!")
  }
}

class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
  // MARK: - Inputs
  enum Inputs {
    case signIn(person: Person)
  }
  var targetPerson: Person?
  
  // MARK: - Outputs
  @Published var isShow = false
//  @Published var isConfirmed = false
  @Published var selectedPerson: Person?
  
  // MARK: - Privates
  private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
  
  @ObservedObject var modalViewModel = ModalViewModel()
  
  init(){
    self.bind()
  }
  
  func apply(_ action: Inputs) {
    switch action {
      case .signIn(let person):
        self.targetPerson = person
        self.isShow = true
    }
  }
  
  func bind() {
    self.modalViewModel
      .$isConfirmed
//      .print("変更されました→\(isConfirmed)")
      .sink { (isConfirmed) in
        if isConfirmed {
          self.selectedPerson = self.targetPerson
          self.isShow = false
        }
      }
      .store(in: &cancellables)
  }
}

class ModalViewModel: ObservableObject {
  // MARK: - Inputs
  enum Inputs {
    case confirm
  }
  
  // MARK: - Outputs
  @Published var isConfirmed = false
  
  init(){}
  
  func apply(_ action: Inputs) {
    switch action {
      case .confirm:
        self.isConfirmed = true
    }
  }
}
```